# Categories not filtering with Low Seg2Cat

Tags: channel-entries, categories, low-seg2cat, category-group

I am having some problem with the Low Seg2Cat extension. I am trying to load all entries for a particular category using the third URI segment. For instance: '/specials/category/europe'. This is the current basic markup:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="specials" orderby="date" category_group="8" category=segment_3_category_id}
<p>{entry_date format='%j%S %M %Y'}</p>
<p>{specials_excerpt}</p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

However, all this outputs at the moment is *any* item that has been categorised. For instance, items categorised as 'Europe' or as 'USA'. Uncategorised items do not appear. Moreover, *any value* entered into segment 3 returns this same list.

I am currently using (and have just upgraded to) EE 2.9.2 before developing this page. Low Seg2Cat is in its latest version, 2.8.1.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is `category=segment_3_category_id}` a typo, or is that your actual code?

Comment: That is the actual code. As mentioned in the comment below, EE 2.9.2 has phased out the use of nesting multiple curly braces, so I have omitted one around 'segment_3_category_id'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like this (note the end of the opening `channel:entries` tag - you were missing a combination of quotes and curly braces):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="specials" orderby="date" category="{segment_3_category_id}"}
    <p>{entry_date format='%j%S %M %Y'}</p>
    <p>{specials_excerpt}</p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I've also omitted the `category_group` parameter, since it is overridden by the `category` parameter.

Be sure that your selected category group is chosen in the Low Seg2Cat extension settings.

I should also add that if you set your [category URL indicator](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/global_channel_preferences.html#category-url-indicator) to "category", then you wouldn't need Low Seg2Cat in this specific case (and you could remove the `category` parameter entirely) - the URL you showed would automatically load all entries in the "europe" catgeory.

> EE 2.9.2 has phased out the use of nesting multiple curly braces

This is not true. You only omit the braces inside of *conditionals* (and even then, sometimes you may still need to use quoted parsed variables there). Everywhere else, variables need braces around them in order to be parsed and used.

Comment: Thanks for the response Derek (I'm working with the original asker on this). I'm now wondering if this is a Seg2Cat bug. We have two different category groups, both of which contain a category with a URL title of 'europe'.

Even though Seg2Cat is configured to search all Category Groups, it's only ever returning the category ID of the 'europe' category in the *other* group, not the one we want.

Comment: Update: Just read the fine-print at the very bottom of Seg2Cat's documentation that explains this is a known caveat: http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat/docs . I'll look into your other suggestion about category URL indicators now, thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Ah, yes - you may need to disable Seg2Cat for one of those category groups in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround `segment_3_category_id` in parethesis and {}

```
category="{segment_3_category_id}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. That's what I had originally but it produced nothing. Apparently in EE 2.9.2, curly braces are being phased out and shouldn't be used in instance such as these.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/conditionals.html#embedding-tags